# Tensorflow: simple linear regression

Tags: tensorflow

I just started to use Tensorflow in python for optimisation problems. And I just gave it a try with really simple regression model. But the results (both slope and constant) I obtain seemed to be quite far off from what I expect, can anyone point out what I have done wrong (the code runs, but I am not sure if I use Tensorflow properly).

What I did:
1 import module:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random as ran
import tensorflow as tf
```

2 create data based on a linear structure (y = 3 X + 4 + error):

```py
train_X = np.array(range(-20,20,1))
b = 3; c = 4; sd = 0.5;
error = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=sd, size=40);
deterministic =  b* train_X + c;
train_Y  = np.add(deter,error)
```

3 setting up for optimisation:

```py
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[40])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[40])

beta = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(), name="beta") 
alpha = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(), name="alpha")

n_samples = 40
learning_rate = 0.01

pred_full = tf.add(tf.scalar_mul(beta, X),alpha)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(tf.subtract(Y, pred_full),2))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

4 Running it:

```py
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y}) 
        result = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y}) 
        result_beta = sess.run(beta, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y}) 
        result_alpha = sess.run(alpha, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y}) 
        print('result:', result, ';', 'result_beta:', result_beta, ';', 'result_alpha:',result_alpha)
```

The result I obtained is:

```py
 result: 1912.99 ; result_beta: 6.75786 ; result_alpha: -0.209623
```

obviously beta is supposed to be close to 3 and alhpa should be close to 4. I am wondering what went wrong in my code?

Thanks

Comment: well you only run your model once...? create a loop and iterate over: cost,opt,beta,alpha=sess.run([cost,optimizer,result_alpha,result_beta], feed=...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the optimizer multiple times for multiple iterations of gradient descent. As, @dv3 noted, try

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(50):
        opt, result_alpha, result_beta = sess.run([optimizer, alpha, beta], feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y})

    print('beta =', result_beta, 'alpha =', result_alpha)
```

NB: It isn't necessary to access multiple tensor values each with individual calls to run(). You can do that with a list of values to fetch.

Comment: Oh, thanks very much appreciate it! I thought with each trail, optimiser would only stop if it cannot find any smaller cost. I have implement the code you gave me. it works!